# Why is こんにちは pronounced as konnichiwa?

Tags: pronunciation

Shouldn't it be pronounced as konnichiha?

Or spelled こんにちわ?

Comment: It's the same reason the particle *wa* is spelled は in kana.  The sound changed, and when they revised kana spelling to better represent modern pronunciation, they kept a few things like は spelled the old way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are talking about 今{こん}日{にち}は?

I guess you can see everything you need by looking at ruby characters above.